# Force USB 3.0 when connecting a device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, udev, modprobe

I have a camera that I would like to be detected as a USB 3.0 device when connecting to the computer. Sometimes, if I don't insert the USB cable quickly enough, the camera gets registered as a USB 2 device. This happens across multiple cameras and multiple high quality cables. The solution is to unplug and re-plug until it is recognized as 3.0. I'm wondering if there is a way to ensure that it is always recognized as USB 3.0, for example, through modprobe or udev rules. I'm not an expert in either of them.

Comment: just to reassure you: that's a design defect on your host's USB connector, or a design flaw in your computer's host USB controller. (I'd normally sigh and say that's most likely the firmware of the USB camera, but it seems you are trying different camera models.) USB conenctors and the connectivity bringup is defined specifically so that this should not happen. Do you have a chance to test whether it still happens with a USB hub in between?

Comment: Yes, It happens when I use a powered USB hub as well. To clarify, all the cameras I've tried are the same model from the same vendor, so it could be a firmware issue of the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the USB Type A plug, the four obvious contact pads are used for the classic USB 2.x speeds. For the higher USB 3.x speeds, there is an additional set of 5 contacts. They are hidden deep within the plug: on the socket side they are more visible, on the "tip of the tongue" of the socket.

Any dirt within the plug or the socket could end up interfering with the "super-speed" contacts while allowing the classic USB 2.x contacts to still work: the classic contacts get a wiping action on every plug/unplug, while the 3.x contacts are basically just pushed against each other. This also means that the 3.x connection is likely to fail if the plug is even slightly askew or otherwise not fully seated.

Since you've tried multiple cameras and cables, carefully inspect the USB socket for dirt or damage.

As the detection as a USB 3.0 device involves a completely different set of wires, no pure software solution can make the connection *switch to* USB 3.0. You could perhaps make an udev rule to reject USB 2.0-mode connections with the device, but then the device would not work at all unless the USB 3.0 contacts were successfully connected.

Such an udev rule would be something like:

```
# Deauthorize a USB device with vendor/productID xxxx:yyyy if it connects as USB 2
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="yyyy", ATTR{speed}=="480", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

This is not exactly what you hoped, but it might still help by making the connection speed problem more immediately obvious when it happens.

Comment: That is a great option. I'd rather the user realize there is a problem immediately.

Comment: Would this be an argument for using a USB Type C plug instead? It seems like the super-speed contacts will have a tendency to be a failure point for the Type A.

Comment: Yes indeed, the Type C plug should be much less finicky for super-speed connections than Type A.